# Restricting access to folder for apps through root permissions

Tags: permissions, files, security

I have a source code folder on my drive and also use an SSH key to communicate with remote repository using git. I only need to use Visual studio code IDE to open the folder and run git commands from within.

If I want to minimize the risk of a compromised app accessing the source code or the SSH key is it a reasonable approach to set root read permissions on both folders and then start the IDE as root? Then the only way those folders could be compromised was if there was malicious code in the IDE or plugins within it.

As far as I've been able to find there is no "restrict access to folder for all apps except X,Y,Z" directive in Linux, not even though AppArmor.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but don't mind reinstalling the system to a newer LTS version.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: I think running an IDE as root will open up more problems for you, especially if it has various plugins installed.  What kind of compromised app are you worried about?  Such an app would have to be installed by you (i.e., via root, I guess?) first.  As for your ssh key, why don't you protect it with a password that unlocks when you log in?

Comment: Rather than changing permissions on your system, iIt will be better to use a dedicated sandboxing tool such as firejail.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm just being cautious, it's not possible to guarantee that there is not a vulnerability in a browser or a generally trustworthy app. I don't plan to install anything obviously shady. The SSH password tip is great. I'd like something of the sort for the folder where the source code is stored -access only after providing a password. Root is not such a good idea I agree.

Comment: It sounds like you want somewhere to store the source but don't want it to be used.  Have you considered just setting up a git repository or something for your code through a self hosted solution like gitea or such?  That way code is stored but can't directly be executed.

Comment: I do need to use and execute it every day I just want to ensure that the possibility of the code leaking from the machine is minimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never run GUI applications (like an IDE) as root.

Create a separate user account that you will be using only for working with the code, make the folder accessible only for that user, and run IDE as that user.

Comment: So my workflow could be: Login as the default user without privileges to the source code. Use this user to open browser or run any other apps besides the IDE. To code, I'd login as the privileged user on a terminal session and open the IDE from there. It should now have access to the source. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. You can also open two sessions simultaneously as two users, by returning to login manager (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and logging in as a different user. The sessions should be displayed on different virtual terminals (probably 2 and 3 by default) so you can just use Ctrl+Alt+F2 and Ctrl+Alt+F3 to switch between them.